# Using Tasseled Cap in ArcGIS Desktop on Landsat TM 4-5 .tif files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

I am attempting to conduct a tasscap Transformation via "Raster Property Functions" on a composite file that I have created from unprocessed, raw data files (meaning tiff-files Bands 1-5 and Band7) via the "composit bands"-tool from Landsat TM 4-5.

The error message occuring when I try to apply the function is as follows:

> The function could not be inserted. The Input or Output arguments are
>   invalid.

Comment: I tried using the tasseled cap imagery function in the past, with no success. I think it's because ["all the information is derived from the input's properties and key metadata (bands, data type, and sensor name)"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000024t000000) but that information is not included when downloading Landsat imagery from GLOVIS. I ended up calculating the tasseled cap "manually" in raster calculator.

Comment: Hi Dmahr! thx, but the tasscap actually does work on "work oder files" (_wo.txt). I have checked that. Problem is that most of the downloadable files from glovis aren't processed by NLAPS and there for contain a _mtl.txt file (new Version). With those I am having my trouble useing the tasscap function.